# Instability of quadratic equations

Tags: floating-point, precision

I'm trying to understand where the loss of precision occur when solving a quadratic equation where the (4ac) term is small compared to the (b) term.

I got that we are subtracting numbers that are close to each other and the result is close to zero. However, I don't quite get why we have alternative algorithm to calculate this solution if we are always aiming for the same really small number (close to zero). I went through the Wikipedia article about this problem but I don't get it. Could anyone provide more insights to my question or maybe ressources for me to understand it better?

Thank you for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the wiki article and alternative algorithm you mentioned?

Comment: There’s a decent [discussion](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2018/04/28/quadratic-formula/) linked from another SO question; I’m not sure reproducing it here is on-topic.

Comment: The OP might be referring to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance#Instability_of_the_quadratic_equation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the classic quadratic formula, (−*b* ± sqrt(*b*<sup>2</sup>−4*ac*)) / (2*a*), a problem arises when 4*ac* is small compared to *b*<sup>2</sup> because:

- The floating-point format used to do the calculations has a limited width (precision), so it is not able to represent *b*<sup>2</sup>−4*ac* with good accuracy. The *b*<sup>2</sup> forces the scale (exponent) to be high, so the low bits of the format are at a somewhat high scale and are incapable of representing the low value of 4*ac* well.
- This error is small relative to *b*<sup>2</sup>−4*ac*, but, when sqrt(*b*<sup>2</sup>−4*ac*) is added to a negative −*b* or subtracted from a positive −*b*, the leading bits cancel, producing a small result, and the error may be great relative to the small result.

On the other hand, the other solution to the equation—the one we get from adding the (positive) square root to a positive −*b* or subtracting it from a negative −*b*—does not suffer this problem. It is a larger number, around −2*b*, so the error in sqrt(*b*<sup>2</sup>−4*ac*) is small relative to it.

Thus the proposal is to calculate this solution *x*<sub>1</sub> first and then use it to find the solution *x*<sub>2</sub> = *c* / (*ax*<sub>1</sub>).

Comment: Thanks you for your detailed answer Eric. It makes it very clear to me know. If I understood correctly this also means that the error is determined by the precision of the largest number. Is that correct?

Comment: @Omnistic: Rounding errors can be very complicated. The largest value can be very influential, but there may be other factors.